# Specify string array in serilog.settings.configuration and appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-table-storage, serilog

I'm trying to use [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) library to configure my logging, and I'm also using [Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage) package and more specifically, the `WriteTo.AzureTableStorageWithProperties`, which accepts a `propertyColumns` argument of type `string[]`.

No matter what I tried, I can't make it work so that I can pass an array of strings in my `appsettings.json` (or using the colon-separated syntax from my environment variables).

I tried doing something like this in `appsettings.json`:

```
WriteTo: [
  // ...
  {
    "Name": "AzureTableStorageWithProperties",
    "Args": {
      // ...
      "propertyColumns": [ "Column1", "Column2" ]
    }
  }
]
```

But I get an error saying that `Argument value should be of type Action<>`.

I tried this: `"propertyColumns": "Column1, Column2"`, but this one also blows (but with a different type of error because it's a different code path).

I also tried using environment variables, e.g.:

```
Serilog:WriteTo:2:Args:propertyColumns:0="Column1"
Serilog:WriteTo:2:Args:propertyColumns:1="Column2"
```

But, again no luck :(

So, is it possible somehow to specify a string array using the library? If so, what am I missing here?

I would really, really appreciate if you help me out here

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you please update the question with whole json config (with other sinks removed) and Serilog configuration code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, I defined my `appsettings.json` as follows to check this issue.

```html
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorageWithProperties",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "<storage-connection-string>",
          "storageTableName": "mylog",
          "propertyColumns": ["Column1","Column2"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
  }
}
```

I could retrieve the same error as you mentioned. Then, I found the similar issues as follows:

[Getting "Argument value should be of type Action<>." with the below appSetting.json](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/58)

[Configuration from appsettings.json](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-loggly/issues/30)

Per my understanding, the complex objects for the `Args` may not be supported by now. Moreover, you could also add your issue under [serilog/serilog-settings-configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I did add [my issue there](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/98) (and in [AzureTableStorage sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage/issues/45)), but I haven't heard back.

Comment: I checked the asynchronous wrapper [Serilog.Sinks.Async](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async), but retrieved the same error.